# Triple for loop in matrix scanning

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, matrix

As say in the title i'm actually using a triple for loop to treat a numpy matrix called A in my python program and , as we can expect, it's very slow.
I have a function that we gonna call "return_bool" which return a boolean in function of a parameter h and i and j the index of the matrix element. I want to use this function for several value of h to make a type of "gradient matrix".
Here is my code :

```
A = np.zero(iindex,jindex)
for h in hvalue:
    for in iindex:
        for j in jindex:
             if (return_bool(h,i,j) : A[i][j] =+ 1
```

Are there any tips to increase the speed of this matrix scanning ?

Here is the code of my "return_bool" function (All the value are float or points (x,y) with x and y points) :

```
def inclu_geo(coord1,coord2,y1,y2 , hh , hh2,y1droite,y2droite, hhdroite , hh2droite,intersec1,intersec2,rho):
    global y
    global yprime
    global largeur_pale
    #equation des droites 
    equdroite1 = eqdroite(y1,y2,hh,hh2)
    equdroite2 = eqdroite(y1droite,y2droite,hhdroite,hh2droite)
    if   0< rho < 90 :
        if (intersec1!=(0,0) or intersec2!=(0,0))and(inclu(intersec1[0],intersec1[1]) or inclu(intersec2[0],intersec2[1])):
            if inclu(intersec1[0],intersec1[1]):
                b = ((y<=coord1<=y1)and(hh2<=coord2<=hh))or((intersec1[0]<=coord1<=yprime)and(hh2<=coord2<=intersec1[1]))or((y1<=coord1<=intersec1[0])and(hh2<=coord2<=(equdroite1[0]*coord1+equdroite1[1])))
            if inclu(intersec2[0],intersec2[1]):
                b = ((y<=coord1<=intersec2[0])and(hh2droite<=coord2<=intersec2[1]))or((y1droite<=coord1<=yprime)and(hh2droite<=coord2<=hhdroite))or((intersec2[0]<=coord1<=y1droite)and(hh2<=coord2<=(equdroite2[0]*coord1+equdroite2[1])))
        else:
            if (hh != 0) and inclu(y1,hh):
                b = ((y<=coord1<=y1)and(hh2<=coord2<=hh))or((y1<=coord1<=y2)and(hh2<=coord2<=(equdroite1[0]*coord1+equdroite1[1])))
            elif (hhdroite != 0) and inclu(y1droite,hhdroite):
                b = ((y1droite<=coord1<=yprime)and(hh2droite<=coord2<=hhdroite))or((y2droite<=coord1<=y1droite)and(hh2<=coord2<=(equdroite2[0]*coord1+equdroite2[1])))
            elif (hhdroite != 0) or (hh != 0):
                b = True
            else:
                b = False
    else:
        if (intersec1!=(0,0) or intersec2!=(0,0))and(inclu(intersec1[0],intersec1[1]) or inclu(intersec2[0],intersec2[1])):
                if inclu(intersec1[0],intersec1[1]):
                    b = ((y<=coord1<=y1)and(hh<=coord2<=hh2))or((intersec1[0]<=coord1<=yprime)and(intersec1[1]<=coord2<=hh2))or((y1<=coord1<=intersec1[0])and((equdroite1[0]*coord1+equdroite1[1])<=coord2<=hh2))
                if inclu(intersec2[0],intersec2[1]):
                    b = ((y<=coord1<=intersec2[0])and(intersec2[1]<=coord2<=hh2droite))or((y1droite<=coord1<=yprime)and(hhdroite<=coord2<=hh2droite))or((intersec2[0]<=coord1<=y1droite)and((equdroite2[0]*coord1+equdroite2[1])<=coord2<=hh2))
        else:
                if (hh != largeur_pale) and inclu(y1,hh):
                    b = ((y<=coord1<=y1)and(hh<=coord2<=hh2))or((y1<=coord1<=y2)and((equdroite1[0]*coord1+equdroite1[1])<=coord2<=hh2))
                elif (hhdroite != largeur_pale) and inclu(y1droite,hhdroite):
                    b = ((y1droite<=coord1<=yprime)and(hhdroite<=coord2<=hh2droite))or((y2droite<=coord1<=y1droite)and((equdroite2[0]*coord1+equdroite2[1])<=coord2<=hh2))
                elif (hhdroite != largeur_pale) or (hh != largeur_pale):
                    b = True
                else:
                    b = False
    return b
```

Comment: Share implementation of `return_bool`?

Comment: in fact it's a kind of "test function" which test the belonging to a geometrical shape and this shape depends of several parameters, i share the code right away

Comment: Could you use a counter instead? The counter via ordered dict should be much much faster. If necessary, you can nest dictionaries as values within outer dictionaries.

Comment: the problem is that i use the matrix after to transform it in a plot like : im = plt.imshow(A, cmap='seismic', interpolation='none') and i suppose that it doesn't work with a counter :/

Comment: The core of the problem is that you have to call `return_bool(h,i,j)` for all combinations of `h,i,j`.  Focus on that.  Can it be rewritten to take a whole range of one or more of those variables at a call?

Comment: In fact my matrix A represent  an average of an image on the day (represent by h the hours) , and each element A[i,j] is a pixel so i can't skip any pixel :/ I'm not sure to understand what you said but i can't skip any pixel

Comment: you seem to be missing a couple of characters in your code examples: `for in iindex:` should probably be `for i in iindex:`, and there is a missing `)` in `if (return_bool(h,i,j) : A[i][j] =+ 1`, presumably before the `:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrite my return_bool(h,i,j) to treat line by line the matrix (return_bool(h,i)), with this method it take 2,5 sec instead of 416 sec , so the problem is solve i guess.
I used "&" and "|" to adapt my logicals equations to an entire line.
Thank you all for your help.